# autWindow is undefined in selenium rc

Tags: selenium, smartgwt

I am recording the script for smart gwt 3.1p by using selenium IDE2.0.0 and I can replay that script successfully in FF20(I have added user_extensions.js & user_extensions_ide.js). But when I export that script to java/junit4/Remote Control & try to run on selenium server some times it runs fine but some times it gives error as follows,

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window.  The er\
ror message is: autWindow is undefined
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:106)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.contextMenu(DefaultSelenium.java:201)
at com.example.tests.adfacereport.testAdFacetest1_rc_junit4(adfacereport.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.runBare(SeleneseTestCase.java:248)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am a new user of selenium. Can anyone please help me regarding this.
[Note: I configured Eclipse build path by adding jar files of selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar & junit-4.11.jar & trying to run my application in local.]

Comment: I just Downgrade my FF20 to FF17 & it worked fine for me... Not sure its compatibility issue or what but after using FF17 it works ... :)